# Multiple copies of a solution on one user/machine with TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to pull two copies of a single solution from TFS 2010 for the same user/machine?

Comment: Mind if I understand why you want two copies of the source in this manner?

Comment: I wanted to keep only one copy of our solution in source control while another dev on our team would like two(one for current work being done, and another that matches the current release).  With only one copy in source control, I'd need to be able to download multiple copies of that same solution. In the case of an emergency fix being needed, I could download another copy of the revision that matches live, code, and roll out - avoiding different branches stored in TFS.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can have multiple copies of a single solution either by having multiple branches in TFS or by setting up different workspaces.

The branches are good for when you need to be able to check in code for both copies of the solution, and have other people work with it too.

I use the multiple workspaces when I need to have a last good state of the code on my dev box while at the same time and still working on new features.

Comment: It doesn't let me create a second workspace that maps to the same solution

Comment: @xanatos are you creating the second workspace in a different local directory?

Comment: thanks a lot! Solved. I was using the "Edit Workspace" instead of the "Add Workspace" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sean L's answer is correct.

My addition is that I coded up some command line calls to do it.
Makes the "What exactly is going on here" stuff a little clearer, IMHO.

Put the below in .bat file.  And save it to c:\ (anywhere you want)......if your BASEDIRECTORY is set to c:\ (somewhere) (or match the drive letters).

```
set __MYWORKSPACENAME=MySuperCoolNewWorkSpaceName001
set __BASEDIRECTORY=c:\tfsstuff\

MD %__BASEDIRECTORY%
CD %__BASEDIRECTORY%

set __tfExe=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe

"%__tfExe%" workspace /new %__MYWORKSPACENAME% /collection:http://myteamfoundationserver:8080/tfs/my_super_cool_projects /noprompt

"%__tfExe%" workfold /map $/MyBranch %__BASEDIRECTORY%\MyBranch


"%__tfExe%" get %__BASEDIRECTORY%\MyBranch\ /recursive /noprompt


set __BASEDIRECTORY=
set __MYWORKSPACENAME=
set __tfExe=
```